# quickblox share image and video in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, xmpp, file-sharing, quickblox

is there any example that how can i share may **image and video** in **quickblox** android SDK? I RND lots of things but I cant find related documents or any other examples there are some example on ios device not in android please help me.

Comment: Share means?.. uploading to their servers right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you already imported the quickblox sdk and all the libraries need by the quickblox sdk.

Their guide pages are right [here.](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-content-android)

And all the quickblox sdk samples are right [here.](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-content)